# firebase: get value with a given key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    mheadingReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.e("one", "======="+snapShot.child("id").getValue(String.class));
                Log.e("one", "======="+snapShot.child("fullname").getValue(String.class));
                Log.e("one", "======="+snapShot.child("password").getValue(String.class));
                Log.e("one", "======="+snapShot.child("type").getValue(String.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I would like to get the values from firebase and I know the keys of the object. Like "key: id" "value: 123456". The code above displays NULL. How will I be able to get the values, like output "123456" alone. Thanks in advance

Comment: show us your database to know why its null, also what is mheadingreference1 equal to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get particular key value from firebase data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291480/how-to-get-particular-key-value-from-firebase-data)

Comment: show you class and database.

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: you might create wrong `reference` instance.so it is giving you `null` values